# 401K or Indian CD

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing, 401k, interest

I am debating on contributing to 401k(which is being invested fully) va putting a sum (say $10k) in Indian CD.

I am assuming investment in stocks would return about 6-8% where as Indian CD would return guaranteed 9.5% a year. Stock investment is not guaranteed

I know the interest on CD is taxed.

Any thoughts?

PS: INR rate is at the highest now. 62.0 for a dollar.

401k match is very low to none. I get about 2% or so overall.

Comment: Is there any match on the 401(k)?

Comment: Unless I am missing something, couldn't you do both. A 401K is just an account. You could hold a CD in a 401K

Comment: Currency conversion rates risk! In the past, people who, lured by the high interest rate, invested in INR CDs by exchanging nonIndian currencies for rupees lost all their gains when the Indian rupee was devalued.

Comment: @JohnFx 401k plans generally restrict investments to a few mutual funds and possibly a annuity, and so investing in a CD is typically not an option. Some401k plans offer a _self-managed_ option that allows 401k money to be invested through a brokerage into stocks and bonds etc (usually available only in plans with lots of high earners), but there is often a larger "administrative" fee for opting for the self-managed plan.

Comment: Sorry. Brain fart there. I saw 401K and was thinking IRA.

Comment: In what currency is the Indian CD? How does that currency behave vs USD?

Comment: @littleadv its INR. current rate is 62 INR a dollar.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem stems with converting your U.S. Dollars to Indian Rupees so as to be able to purchase an Indian fixed deposit.

At the time of writing this, 1 U.S. Dollar = 64 Indian Rupees. Consider the following economic factors:

- India is trying to ramp up exports which is helped by a relatively weaker rupee which in turn means that the Indian government might not be too worried if the rupee was to further depreciate
- A potential increase in interest rates in the U.S. could also lead to dollar appreciates versus other currencies

**Both of the above factors are not definitive** but are worth considering.

You might be thinking- what if I never intend to convert my rupees back to dollars? If it is the case that money converted to rupees would stay that way, that then eliminates the risk of foreign exchange losses mentioned above.

However, you must still keep in mind that part of the reason interest rates on fixed deposits is as high in India is because inflation is high. A 9% return must be looked at after adjusting for inflation. Inflation is somewhere between 5%-6% at the time of writing which then reduces your real return to about 4% (pre-tax).